# do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables for example - Individuals and Emails

Table - Individuals 
Columns 
Indv_ID (PK)
Email_ID

Table Emails 
Columns 
Email_ID (PK)
Email_Type  (PK)
Email_Address

The idea is that the same individual can have multiple emails. So, if Joe has two emails, and joes ID is 100.

```
**TABLE - INDIVIDUALS**
Indv_ID           Email_ID
100               200

**TABLE - EMAILS**
Email_ID        Email_Type      Email_Address
200             PERSONNEL       joe.john@yahoo.com
200             WORK            joe.john@abc.com
```

Now, I am trying to define this relationship. Basically, between EMAIL_ID column in INDIVIDUAL and EMAIL_ID & EMAIL_TYPE in EMAILS.

When I try to define the Foreign key relationship, I am getting the following error.

"The Columns in table INDIVIDUALS do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint"

Please let me know how to handle this and define this type of relations.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish your goal, the best design would be:

Table - Individuals Columns

```
Indv_ID (PK)
```

Table Emails Columns

```
Email_ID (PK)
Email_Type (PK)
Indv_ID (PK)
Email_Address
```

So:

```
**TABLE - INDIVIDUALS**
Indv_ID           
100               

**TABLE - EMAILS**
Email_ID        Email_Type      INDV_ID      Email_Address
300             PERSONNEL       100          joe.john@yahoo.com
400             WORK            100          joe.john@abc.com
```

Conclusion:

Every individual has many emails. You can change the primary keys of the Email table as your business need. But thats the idea.

Another tip:

Consider enumerate your Email_Type column for an integer type or a char value.

Comment: I have another table (for example - CONTRACTORS) referring emails to EMAILS Table. If I keep the Indv_id from INDIVIDUALS Table and Indv_id from CONTRACTORS table in the same column (INDV_ID) in EMAILS Table, I may get in problem because there is a possibility that an individual and contractor can get same ID. Please check this situation. Can you suggest a design which can handle this also.

Comment: INDIVIDUALS and CONTRACTORS share the same email?

Comment: No. INDIVIDUAL-1 has INDV_ID 100, EMAIL indv@hotmail.com. A contractor can have same INDV_ID 100 in CONTRACTOR Table.

Comment: Sorry, didnt get it...post your CONTRACTORS table ddl please?

Comment: **TABLE - CONTRACTOR**<BR>
INDV_ID<BR>
100

Comment: CONTRACTOR Table has a column called INDV_ID as primary key and many other columns

Comment: This kind messy. You have a table CONTRACTOR with an INDV_ID primary key. If CONTRACTOR is a specialization of the INDIVIDUALS table, you wont have problems with my design.

Comment: Say there is a contractor with indv_id as 100 and an individual with indv_id as 100. How do I query the emails for this individual and contractor

Comment: Update your question with the CONTRACTOR table and its relation to others tables. Therefore I update my answer to meet your requirements :)

Comment: Based on my current design all main columns in CONTRACTOR Table is same as INDIVIDUAL Tables. INDV_ID and Email ID. So, logically I am not getting any issue in storing the data. For example a contractor with INDV_ID 100 will have a email_ID as 300. So, it works. But I can not define the relationship, which I mentioned in my original question.